# Alternative ways to submit data

Tags: google-forms

I'm working on a project where google forms will be used to submit data for an assessment. Users will be accessing the forms through drive, and then submitting the same form many times.

My question is: are there any alternative ways to open the data collection process other than previewing the form or sending emails? It would be nice if there was a way I could let users start submitting data but not allow them to edit the form. Emails, in this case, are not practical.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There is a different web address for the Google Form for "View" mode than "Edit" mode.  If you must have them navigate first to Google Drive, then add a link to the Google Form into a Google Doc, and have them open the Doc, and then click on the link to the Form.  A Google Form can be embedded into a website.  I can be easier to navigate to a website with a domain name.  In either case the user needs an address to enter into their browser, or a link to click on.  You could have a Google Site, with a page that has a link to the Form.

Comment: @SandyGood This was not the solution I was hoping for but it will probably work. Thanks for your suggestion!